# How can I shift individual cells in XY-pic without shifting the corresponding row/column?

Tags: tables, xy-pic

I'd like to create a figure using XY-pic in which one cell actually spans two rows (like \multirow).
Should look something like:

```
1,1       1,3
     BIG
2,1       3,3
```

With arrows from 1,1 and 2,1 to BIG and from BIG to 1,3 and 3,3.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\xymatrix{
1,1 \ar[dr] & & 1,3 \\
2,1 \ar[r] & \multirow{2}{*}{BIG} \ar[ur] \ar[r] & 2,3 \\
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I feel like there is a modifier on the element (some kind of *+5pt{BIG}) that would work, but I don't grok the Xy-pic user's manual. I did find some black magic that would shift the cell up but also increased the space between rows. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three rows and reduce the spacing between them:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,pdf]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@R-1pc{
  1,1 \ar[dr] && 1,2 \\
  & BIG \ar[ur] \ar[dr] \\
  2,1 \ar[ur] && 2,2
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Test]

Comment: Unfortunately, this hack won't work for me afaict.  The MWE is actually a part of a much larger table.  Maybe I could figure out how to collapse them...

Comment: Okay, so after some extensive reworking of the table, this solution hacked it.  Thanks!